# Strange Azure start up error ( Could not find file 'c:\logs\file1.txt')

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

Worker role is pretty simple and runs in emulator OK. After uploading up to Windows Azure instances seems to initialize, become busy then restart and start over again. Azure Diagnostics do not ship any of our own trace messages and keeps delivering flowing lines over and over again:

> Information: RD00155D3629BA: 2011-08-22 17:41:26Z OnTimedEvent Start 8/22/2011 5:41:26 PM
>
> Information: RD00155D3629BA: 2011-08-22 17:40:26Z OnTimedEvent Completed
>
> Error: RD00155D3629BA: 2011-08-22 17:40:26Z Could not find file 'c:\logs\file2.txt'.
>
> Information: RD00155D3629BA: 2011-08-22 17:40:26Z Copying c:\logs\file2.txt
>
> Error: RD00155D3629BA: 2011-08-22 17:40:26Z Could not find file 'c:\logs\file1.txt'.
>
> Information: RD00155D3629BA: 2011-08-22 17:40:26Z OnTimedEvent Start 8/22/2011 5:40:26 PM
>
> Information: RD00155D3629BA: 2011-08-22 17:40:26Z OnTimedEvent Start 8/22/2011 5:40:26 PM

**Edit:** No code in this small application writes to mentioned files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several "favorite" reasons why a role doesn't start up correctly and cycles through the various stages.  Here's a blog posting with a pretty good list of them:

http://blog.toddysm.com/2010/01/windows-azure-deployment-stuck-in-initializing-busy-stopping-why.html

The most popular in my experience is failure to include all dependencies in the role during deployment.

Comment: Does not assembly loader write errors to Application event log?